# Extracting values from curve fit (Python)

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

Hi i am fitting data via curve fit:

```
 mu100,sigma100 = curve_fit(norm.cdf, data_framie_file_101_comps_10um['stimn'], data_framie_file_101_comps_10um['soma'], p0=[0,1])[0]
```

when i plot this, i get

[image]

How can i extract from curve fit the x-value where for example the spiking probability equals 0.9?

Thank you

Comment: How are you plotting this graph? If you can provide some insight on that it will be much easier for folks to answer your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is to calculate the inverse of `norm.cdf` which is `norm.ppf` (mentioned under section [Methods](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html)) with the fitted parameters `mu100` and `sigma100`. So, `norm.ppf(0.9, mu100, sigma100)`.